# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog(...).dialog(...).dialogExtend is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to add a dialog widget to my table using dialogextend jquery plugin. I am getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog(...).dialog(...).dialogExtend is not a function when using dialogextend jquery plugin.

Below is my code:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas">
        <ul>li><a href="#">Table</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </canvas>
    <script>
        $("#canvas").dialog("open")
            .dialog({
            height: 500,
            width: 1200,
            resizable: true,
            open: function(type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            },
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        })

            .dialogExtend({
            "closable": true,
                "minimizable": true,
                "minimizeLocation": "right",
                "icons": {
                "close": "ui-icon-circle-close",
                    "minimize": "ui-icon-circle-minus",
                    "restore": "ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"
            }
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: put your code inside of $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: I tried but didn't work.

Comment: FYI i am getting the following error now Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog(...).dialog(...).dialogExtend is not a function.

Comment: have you include jQuery DialogExtend js file ?

Comment: Yeah ofcourse i did.

Comment: put your code in  $(document).ready this may solve the problem

Comment: Yes I tried that too. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open dialog box before  initialize,You have to initialize the dialog before being able to open it:

try :

```
  $("#canvas").dialog({
            height: 500,
      autoOpen: false,
            width: 1200,
            resizable: true,
            open: function(type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            },
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        })

            .dialogExtend({
            "closable": true,
                "minimizable": true,
                "minimizeLocation": "right",
                "icons": {
                "close": "ui-icon-circle-close",
                    "minimize": "ui-icon-circle-minus",
                    "restore": "ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"
            }
        }).dialog("open");
```

[here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qNHKr/44/)

Comment: what browser you are using ? link working fine on my browser

Comment: I am using chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit).

Comment: if you have any other browser please check on it

Comment: Yeah it runs on firefox without issue.

Comment: Document.ready didnot work in chrome. The fiddle link is working in firefox.

Comment: I just run the fiddle in chrome. Nothing is being displayed in result. Even there are no errors also.

Comment: Chrome netbeans connector is giving the follwing error: cartodb.js 3.15.8 (07:17:08:884)
  at http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js:16
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog(...).dialogExtend is not a function (07:17:19:345 | error, javascript)
    at (anonymous function) (public_html/drag_drop_ui.html:105:38)
    at j (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2:26860)
    at k.fireWith (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2:27673)
    at x (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4:11120)
    at (anonymous function) (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4:14767)